# Extended Doctrine entities create incorrect SQL

Tags: php, sql, doctrine-orm, query-builder

For a certain setup I have this configuration:

`Foo\Entity\Article` > `LibI18n\Entity\Article` > `Lib\Entity\AbstractArticle`. So there are two classes and one abstract which all inherit properties from each other. The abstract, i18n and foo classes all have their own fields and (XML) mapping. Now if I query a Foo article, there is some incorrect SQL generated as I get his error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'b0_.publish_date' in 'field list'

The query is this:

```
SELECT
    b0_.publish_date AS publish_date0,
    b0_.id AS id1, 
    b0_.blog_id AS blog_id2, 
    m1_.image_id AS image_id3
FROM foo_article m1_
WHERE
    m1_.publish_date IS NOT NULL
    AND m1_.publish_date <= ? 
    AND b0_.blog_id = ? 
ORDER BY m1_.publish_date DESC
LIMIT 3

// with params ["2013-09-10 12:02:08", 1]
```

As noticed, all `b0` should be replaced with `m1`. Apparently, Doctrine does not understand my mapping. The `image_id` field corresponds to the `Foo` namespace. The `publish_date`, `id` and `blog_id` are all properties from the `AbstractArticle`.

The question: how can this be fixed? It is quite a lot of php/XML code to publish about the entities and the corresponding mapping, so it's all in a gist: https://gist.github.com/juriansluiman/e063c8cfcd9e27288d27

**UPDATE 1**

Used modules:

- DoctrineORMModule: 0.7.0
- DoctrineModule: 0.7.2

Doctrine libraries:

- doctrine/orm: 2.4.0
- doctrine/dbal: 2.4.0
- doctrine/common: 2.4.1
- doctrine/collections: 1.1
- doctrine/cache: 1.1
- doctrine/annotations: 1.1.2
- doctrine/inflector: 1.0
- doctrine/lexer: 1.0

**UPDATE 2**

This is the repository class:

```
class Article extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findRecent(BlogEntity $blog, $limit)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');
        $qb->andWhere('a.blog = :blog')
           ->setParameter('blog', $blog)
           ->setMaxResults($limit);

        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }

    public function createQueryBuilder($alias, $constraints = true)
    {
        $qb = parent::createQueryBuilder($alias);

        if (true === $constraints) {
            $qb->andWhere('a.publishDate IS NOT NULL')
               ->andWhere('a.publishDate <= :now')
               ->setParameter('now', new DateTime)
               ->orderBy('a.publishDate', 'DESC');
        }

        return $qb;
    }
}
```

This generates the following DQL (just before the `$qb->getQuery()` call):

```
SELECT a
FROM Foo\Entity\Article a
WHERE
    a.publishDate IS NOT NULL
    AND a.publishDate <= :now
    AND a.blog = :blog
ORDER BY a.publishDate DESC
```

Comment: Do you have any details on the ORM version? Are mappings validated correctly?

Comment: @Ocramius updated question, added modules + Doctrine libs :) And yes, mappings and database fields are all green. Thanks for answering!

Comment: Can you also add the DQL query that causes this?

Comment: Is is just me or are you missing the inheritance mapping inheritance map for the discriminator column?

Comment: I don't want to use single table inheritance. Just using the abstract in the OOP sense that it provides some fields for my `Lib` article (defaults if no other fields are required) or `Foo` article (if this specific client needs additional fields). Without `Foo` (but including the article from `LibI18n`) it just works, only the three-level inheritance fails apparently.

Comment: no, this won't work if you extend an entity. You have to only extend mapped superclasses, or doctrine will consider it an inheritance.

Comment: Maxing your points here :P You gave me the right clue. The mapping was `Foo` > `Bar` > `Baz` with only `Baz a mapped superclass. I now made `Bar` a superclass too, which caused only the "end point" to be an entity. Thanks!

Comment: Put it as an answer and mark it as correct then, or I can sum it up when I have time.